# CMake appears to be ignoring a line?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a CMakeLists.txt file, with these few lines:

```
include(CheckSymbolExists)
check_symbol_exists(alloca stdlib.h;cstdlib ALLOCA_EXISTS)
check_symbol_exists(malloc stdlib.h;cstdlib MALLOC_EXISTS)
```

But in the relevant part of the CMake output, all that appears is this:

```
...
-- Looking for alloca
-- Looking for alloca - found
...
```

Nothing about `malloc` appears at all. Is CMake ignoring my line? Or is something else happening?

**Edit:**

I even tried this...

```
unset(CMAKE_REQUIRED_QUIET)
```

... before each call to `check_symbol_exists`, which didn't solve the problem.

Comment: If you add `--trace` parameter to the cmake command it will give you more output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of playing around with my CMakeLists file and documentation reading, I realized my mistake was twofold.

First, I didn't put the file list in quotes, so thanks +Tsyvarev for the answer.

I realized the second part of my error when reading the `check_symbol_exists` documentation, and found this:

> If the check needs to be done in C++, consider using CHECK_CXX_SYMBOL_EXISTS(), which does the same as CHECK_SYMBOL_EXISTS(), but in C++.

Link: [CheckSymbolExists](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/CheckSymbolExists.html)

So I realized I should be using `check_cxx_symbol_exists` because `check_symbol_exists` won't be able to look through C++ headers.

After changing the macro calls and the import line, my script worked as expected.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

For pass a *list* as a *single argument* to a function/macro, the list **should be enclosed** into double quotes:

```
# Double quotes are required around the list argument
check_symbol_exists(alloca "stdlib.h;cstdlib" ALLOCA_EXISTS)
```

Double quotes around list argument are not needed only if this is the *last non-positional* argument:

```
# Here double quotes can be omited.
set(A a;b;c)
```

---

Without double quotes your code is interpreted as

```
check_symbol_exists(alloca stdlib.h cstdlib ALLOCA_EXISTS)
check_symbol_exists(malloc stdlib.h cstdlib MALLOC_EXISTS)
```

that is `cstdlib` becomes 3-d argument to the macro, which denotes the variable where result should be stored. Given variable is created at the first call (check for `alloca`). The second call (check for `malloc`) checks the variable, finds it as already been set, interprets this as "the check has already been performed", and does nothing.

Comment: Have you modified **both** lines in such way?